# laravel raw php query to order varchar column as number

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working with php Laravel Framework. So I have made a query to order a column called price which it's a varchar datatype in MySQL database asc.

```
$data =  Data::selectRaw('Dbname.tablename.*, Convert(price ,decimal )  as price  )->orderBy('price','asc')->where('service_id',$service_id) ->limit(100)->get(array('price' ));
```

The problem

If there value  like 350,000 the output displayed in the page as  just 350
or value like 5,000,000 it displayed as  5.

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with your data not Laravel. Does this raw query work if you just run it directly on your database? If not, then it's definitely not Laravel's fault. You *might* be able to get round it by having the following as your select column: ``CONVERT(REPLACE(`price`, ',', ''), DECIMAL) AS `price` `` But doing a string replace and format conversion on every result in the query in order to sort by the transformed column isn't exactly good practice. It'd be much better to just have this column in the correct format in the first place.

Comment: I think this is my only way to solve the problem-  It'd be much better to just have this column in the correct format in the first place